# Mouse anti-tremor solution?

Tags: windows-xp, mouse, accessibility

My 73 year old mother is a surprisingly savvy computer user.  She uses her computer for research almost daily.  As she has gotten older, she has developed a tremor in both hands.  This makes using the mouse difficult when clicking on small items on the screen.  She currently uses Windows XP.  Is there software or hardware that can dampen her tremor so she can continue to use enjoy her computer?

Comment: Any update on what worked for you?

Comment: Mom is being stubborn.  She is insisting that there is no need for help.  Give her some time and maybe she'll soften.  <sigh>

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [SteadyMouse](http://www.steadymouse.com/)? It looks like it was designed for your needs. Hasn't been updated (from the looks of it) for a while- but if it does what you need who cares (runs on XP).

And then there's [this crazy expensive solution](http://www.enablingtechnology.net/anti-tremor-mouse-adapter-119-p.asp), but I'd try the free software first.

Comment: I'll try the SteadyMouse.

Comment: http://www.montrosesecam.com/index.html  I believe is the main source for the above device.

Comment: @DHayes Looks like it, still a bit pricey.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered the accessibility options to [Control the mouse pointer with the keyboard (Mouse Keys)](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsvista/mousekeys.aspx).

That should allow her to move around the screen with the mouse and then switch to the keyboard for more precise movement.

[image]

Here are the [accessibility options in Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/windowsxp/mousekeys.aspx).

[image]

Comment: This seems to be available in WinXP but looks very different.

Comment: I added the XP-specific links.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing else, reducing the mouse movement speed could make more accurate clicking easier

[image: Mouse Motion Speed]

**Edit:** On a side note, my mother also has some slight hand tremors, although not that bad, but has an easier time using a [Trackball](http://www.rebeltech.co.za/images/Logitech%20Cordless%20Trackman%20Trackball.jpg) instead of a mouse. Results may vary.

Comment: We tried this.  The slowness made it easier to click, but annoying for everything else.  She put it back to the original setting.

Comment: Love that 'she put it back'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are third party options to do this, but I'm not aware of them. If I could propose an alternative though, you may look at increasing the size of the icons. This way normal users without a tremor won't be adversely affected.

Comment: This would only work in Windows itself.  She uses lots of applications that would not benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using keyboard shortcuts rather than point and click would help her use the computer better without making her feel useless.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion:  A trackball.  A hand tremor won't move them.